# kubeflow - what is the username and password to login to the default example kubeflow deployment?

Tags: kubeflow

What is the kubeflow ui default username and password for the default example deployment of kubeflow?

The kubeflow manifest version is 1.5.0 which has been deployed by following the instruction in the page.

```
while ! kustomize build example | kubectl apply -f -; do echo "Retrying to apply resources"; sleep 10; done
```

The URL for the UI:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/services/http:istio-ingressgateway:80/proxy/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Kubeflow Manifests](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests#dex%5C)

> Dex is an OpenID Connect Identity (OIDC) with multiple authentication backends. In this default installation, it includes a static user with **email user@example.com**. By default, the user's **password is 12341234**. For any production Kubeflow deployment, you should change the default password by following the relevant section.